# How can I create restricted signing key or attestation key and certify it in TPM 2.0?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing, remote-attestation

I need to create an attestation key (AK) and use it to sign arbitrary data in TPM 2.0. The TCG Guidance documents, suggest that some TPMs may come pre-provisioned with an AK that is part of the endorsement hierarchy. I am wondering if there is way to tell whether a TPM has such a key and if not what is the best way to create one and prove that this AK is bound to the TPM's EK?